# Node.js chat app and clusters

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, cluster-computing

I'd like to make chatroulette app with node.js and: socket.io, cluster - modules/plugins.

So I have master-cluster who just create a few sub-clusters.
Now, each sub-cluster has socket.io connection on same port. But where should I combine into pairs all sockets(users), in which sub-cluster? Some sockets are in one cluster, and some sockets in other cluster.

I can sync all socket.io connections by this clusterhub:
http://toolbox.no.de/packages/socket.io-clusterhub

So each cluster has all sockets, but which sub-cluster should combine sockets into pairs?
Generally I need to do some things over sub-clusters, and need access to all sockets from all sub-clusters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to connect your different socket.io instances with either Message Queue or a Socket.IO Store so they communicate with each other and pass of the message to a different instance.

Socket.IO already has a concept of Stores which is used to store connections it's socket.io's answer to deploying multiple servers and processes. Socket.IO ships with 2 stores, the memory store that will keep all connection information inside process and a RedisStore that will sync all the information between all the connected processes.

See https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO (section about stores) for more information on how you can implement that.

Comment: socket.io-clusterhub plugin doing things of syncing socket.io instances, so im gonna use it, but what about where should I connect users into pairs in which instance? And other subject if client will sends message to socket.io will every instance of socket.io get it so then will be double events or triple.. etc.